If rank of T is finite then spectrum of T is a finite set
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $T$ be a compact operator on $H$. Show that if the rank of $T$ is finite then the spectrum of $T$ is a finite set.
$\textbf{My attempt.}$
First thing I noticed was that if rank of $T$ is finite, then that means the dimension of the Im($T$) is finite, in other words, Im($T$) is spanned by some finite basis.
Second thing I noticed was that by spectral theory of compact operators, the non-zero spectrum coincides with the non-zero eigenvalues, and so we can just analyse the number of non-zero eigenvalues.
The last thing I noticed was that in our course, we had just recently proven a result which states:
for any real $t>0$, the set of all non-zero, distinct eigenvalues with $|t|>0$ is finite.
So my thought was that by using the fact that $T$ is finite rank, we can somehow conclude that $T$ attains some minimum eigenvalue, which then allows us to bound $|t|$ below by say $|t_0|>0$, and thus there is only a finite number of eigenvalues. Then finally, we can conclude that the spectrum of $T$ is a finite set.
$\textbf{My Problem.}$
I however am unsure as to whether this is on the right track, and if it is on the right track, if I am forgetting some fact about eigenvalues which allows us to claim that a finite rank operator attains a minimum eigenvalue.
Any hints would be appreciated!

You just need to remember that eigenvectors associated to distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent!

Oh wow, that makes things so much easier. Thank you!
